# How is lava ferrous oxides responding to Earth's magnetic field related to Curie temperature?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth

One of the evidences of Earth's magnetic field oscilations are different magnetic orientations of lava particles that pop up on the surface at several volcanic locations at several chronologic stages a long time ago and now can be observed...But if Curie temerature can disturb magnetisation even while a material is still solid how then lava particles accuired their orientations? I know that iron can be magnetised nevertheless it is solid but why then lava particles from different pariods haven't do the same and all align with the acctual Earth's magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

when the lava is deposited, it is above its Curie temperature. As it cools below that temperature *in the presence of the earth's magnetic field*, it assumes the magnetization direction of that field, the domains get "frozen" in place, and it becomes a permanent magnet.